# Firebase Android - datasnapshot not returning all the fields in onChildChanged()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When my app loads, the datasnapshot returns all the fields in the child listener in the onChildAdded() method which is how I populate a local list variable called TaskGroups from the datasnapshot and below is the contents of that datasnapshot

```
taskGroupList={KYTD1647450187={taskGroupName=Task, taskGroupID=KYTD1647450187, taskGroupColorString=#FFFF0BFF}, AONS1647450187={taskGroupName=Fitness, taskGroupID=AONS1647450187, taskGroupColorString=#FF6E2E7B}, BNZH1648154782={taskGroupName=School, taskGroupID=BNZH1648154782, taskGroupColorString=#FF6E2E7C}
```

and here is what it looks like on Firebase before adding anything

[image]

But when I attempt to add a new "taskgroup" from my Android app (I just added new taskgroup "Apdjf" just for this example), all the correct fields are uploaded to Firebase shown in the image below

[image]

However in the onChildChanged() method of the same listener of my app, I don't receive all the fields for the new "taskgroup" that I just added. Instead I'm only getting the "taskGroupID" for the newly added taskgroup and missing the "taskGroupColorString" and the "taskGroupName" fields and I need all this info to rebuild a certain part of my app. Below is what my datasnapshot gives me

```
taskGroupList={HDCL1649906550={taskGroupID=HDCL1649906550}, KYTD1647450187={taskGroupName=Task, taskGroupID=KYTD1647450187, taskGroupColorString=#FFFF0BFF}, AONS1647450187={taskGroupName=Fitness, taskGroupID=AONS1647450187, taskGroupColorString=#FF6E2E7B}, BNZH1648154782={taskGroupName=School, taskGroupID=BNZH1648154782, taskGroupColorString=#FF6E2E7C}
```

What is going on?

This is the Java code that gets called when I add a new "TaskGroup" to the database

```
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               if (childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").getValue() != null) {
                    String taskGroupId = generateTaskGroupID();
                    childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").child(taskGroupId).child("taskGroupID").getRef().setValue(taskGroupId);
                    childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").child(taskGroupId).child("taskGroupColorString").getRef().setValue(finalDatabaseTaskGroupColorString[0]);
                    childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").child(taskGroupId).child("taskGroupName").getRef().setValue(taskGroupSelected);
                }
          }
                                            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing three separate write operations in the code you shared here:

```
childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").child(taskGroupId).child("taskGroupID").getRef().setValue(taskGroupId);
childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").child(taskGroupId).child("taskGroupColorString").getRef().setValue(finalDatabaseTaskGroupColorString[0]);
childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").child(taskGroupId).child("taskGroupName").getRef().setValue(taskGroupSelected);
```

If `taskGroupId` is a new unique ID, then the first call to `setValue` (`setValue(taskGroupId)`) generates an `onChildAdded` event, while the other two `setValue` calls generate `onChildChanged` events.

To prevent this from happening, you should add all child nodes in a single write operation, for example with:

```
Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("taskGroupID", taskGroupId);
values.put("taskGroupColorString", finalDatabaseTaskGroupColorString[0]);
values.put("taskGroupName", taskGroupSelected);

childDataSnapshot.child("taskGroupList").child(taskGroupId).setValue(values);
```

Now there's only a single write operation, so this will (if the `taskGroupId` is a new unique ID) only result in a single `onChildAdded` call with all three properties.